# under what conditions stochastic exponential is a usual exponential?

Tags: stochastic-analysis

Stochastic exponential is

$\mathcal{E}_t(X)=e^{X_t-\frac{1}{2}<X^c>_t}\prod_{s\leq t}(1+\Delta X_t)e^{-\Delta X_s}$

and usual exponential is $e^{X_t}$

I guess, if process is continuous and of finite variation then it they should be the same, right? any weaker conditions?